# How To Convert Morse Key Input To Audio

Tags: audio-interface, morse-code, audio

I am thinking of purchasing a [TYT TH-9800](https://www.radioddity.com/collections/mobile-radio/products/tyt-th-9800-quad-band-mobile-radio-programming-cable) Plus. Its only drawback is there is no input for a CW device.

What Equipment would be required to convert CW output into audio input?

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I have never held that device in my hand, but:

That is an FM radio. So, you enable its transmission and transmit silence, you get a stable CW tone. (You transmit anything but silence, you also get a single frequency at its output, but it moves - that's the frequency getting modulated in FM.)

To Morse, you would just need to disable and enable transmission accordingly. The "modification" you'd need to do is connecting your paddle to the push-to-talk button input.

Herein lies the problem: it's questionable whether the device is designed to turn the transmission on and off quick enough to allow for Morse keying. So, you'd really want to find out whether someone has tried that before.

Comment: Turning the transmission on and off too quickly will generate key clicks, which will increase your bandwidth and annoy others close to your frequency. And connecting a key to the PTT line will do exactly that.

Comment: That is very true for hard switching, but we don't know how the specific device handles the end and start of transmissions. Seeing this is very likely a thoroughly digital device with power control, there's no reason for clicks. Most importantly: it's not like we have any other option with an FM-only device, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sending is only part of it. It still needs an envelope detector and a BFO.

Comment: Sending and receiving MCW would be far easier, assuming that it's legal.

Comment: At least the radio has an AM receive-only mode, and with a bit of offset tuning, that would make for beeps, as long as that AM mode supports suppressed carrier modes

Comment: Sorry, new abbreviation to me: what's MCW? Edit: aaaah f2a, Morse in audio baseband of FM. Is that commonly used? Feels like the worst of two worlds!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151808/discussion-between-mike-waters-and-sina-bala).